# How to disable spinning of post from a php subdirectory file of a script

Tags: php

I am actually a newbie and I have the following code line in my spin.php file in my includes directory.

```
function turbo_spin($post,$lang) { //Define spin Class require_once('spinbase.php');

//lang check if ($lang =="" || $lang== null) { $lang = "en"; } //spin the data //$data = stripslashes($post); $spin=new spin_my_data; $spinned=$spin->spin($post,$lang);

//select any random synonymous word $spinned_data=$spin->split($spinned);
return $spinned_data; }
```

How can i diable this spin.php from executing

Answer (score 0):

just put a `return;` after the function definition.

Comment: Do you mean like this  function turbo_spin($post,$lang) { //Define spin Class require_once('spinbase.php');return;